# tradução dos adjetivos do inglês para o português que terminam com *morphic

Tags: tradução-inglês

A minha dúvida surgiu a partir da tradução do termo **homomorphic image** para a língua portuguesa. Encontra-se tanto **imagem homomorfa** como **imagem homomórfica**. Outra situação que tenho familiaridade é **holomorphic function**. Traduz-se este termo como **função holomorfa** ou como **função holomórfica**. Existe alguma regra que determine como deve ser feito a tradução para o português deste sufixo?

Comment: homeomorphic, não homomorphic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe, em mineralogia, o adjectivo "iso**morfo**"  (vide [infopedia.pt](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/isomorfo)) e também na matemática. No caso das funções, em livros recentes portugueses, aparecem designadas por "holo**morfas**", à semelhança do  francês ("fonction holomorphe"). Isto é, o sufixo **-morfo** tem-se vindo a generalizar, pelo menos nesse mesmo contexto técnico, como, por exemplo, "homeo**morfo**". O mesmo sufixo também se usa em "função mero**morfa**".

De salientar que estes adjetivos derivam dos substantivos correspondentes: holomorfismo, meromorfismo, isomorfismo, homeomorfismo, etc.

> Existe alguma regra que determine como deve ser feito a tradução para o português deste sufixo?

Desconheço, mas para além de um possível uso diferente num ou noutro domínios muito específicos, diria que se deve usar preferencialmente o sufixo **-morfo/a** para **-morphic**.

Comment: Sim, esse morphic se transforma em morfo.